# Loop command for convert folders into .ISO files

Tags: windows

I'm using powerISO utility command on Windows
To create one ISO file from a folder i use this command

```
piso create -o C:\test\File.iso -add C:\test\File.iso /
```

`-o` Specify output image file name

But inside C:\test i have 10-20 folders that i want convert. I try this command to create for each folder a ISO file where every ISO have same name of folder, but doesn't work

```
 piso create C:\test\ "${folder%/}.iso"
```

I try to understand loop command but i don't understand nothing
http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your piso tool but see if you can get some clue from this code - put your folder in the cd command and run it to see the way it uses the folder names.

```
@echo off
cd /d "c:\main\folder"
for /d %%a in (*) do (
   echo command -output "c:\ISO folder\%%a.iso" -input "%%~fa\*.*"
)
pause
```

Comment: I try using this command but output is so http://imageshack.com/a/img538/5724/d0IE3e.png. I see this .bat recognize folders but then..?

Comment: Your question has a syntax that uses the same `c:\test\file.iso` for output and also being added.  That's now how it works, right?  I can't give you the exact command as your example code seems wrong.

Comment: Your command seems to be work because it give no errors, you're right but i don't understand why i haven't ISO output. What can i do? 1. create a bat file and copy-paste your code exactly? If my folders to be convert are in C:\test, can u write me the edited code , please? I try to edit your path into mine but i haven't results.

Comment: My example code doesn't create an ISO.  You need to find out the correct command using your `piso` tool before it can be added to the batch file.